# Why does the initialvalue not update and display?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have returned patient IC number from the RegisteredPatient widget, however the initialvalue does not update and display. I have tried printing the value of the patient IC but I do not understand why the initialvalue does not update. I have even tried with setstate as well.

```
TextFormField(
  initialValue: ic,
  validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter patient IC' : null,
  decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
    hintText: 'Patient IC e.g. 960XXXXXXXXX'
  ),
  onChanged: (val) {
    setState(() => ic = val);
  },
  onTap: () async {
    ic = await Navigator.push(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisteredPatient())
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: You mean when you type something ic value does not updated and nothing change on screen?

Comment: the ic value actually has a value that was returned from the RegisteredPatient widget. but the initialvalue does not update to show.

Comment: Can you share the code of your `RegisteredPatient` widget and also the widget that display TextFormField?

Comment: There's information missing in your question. Why do you want to change the initialValue property. Its only purpose is to be there initially, not to changed afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want the value of the textfield to update when you come back from the RegisteredPatient route. To do this, you should do the following:
**Declaration**

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController =  TextEditingController();
```

**on your TextFormField**

```
onTap: () async {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisteredPatient())
  ).then((newIcValue){
    setState(() {
      _textEditingController.text = newIcValue;
    });
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextFormField`'s lifecycle is managed internally by it's own state (`_TextFormFieldState`), where it has a `TextEditingController` if you don't provide your own and will set an `initialValue` ***only*** the first time the widget is built and inserted in the tree (thus, create the `RenderObject` for that widget).

You can take a look of the `_TextFormFieldState` and see where the `initialValue` is used.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.controller == null) {
      _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialValue);
    } else {
      widget.controller.addListener(_handleControllerChanged);
    }
  }
```

This means, that unless you completely destroy/remove that widget from the tree (for example, by closing the screen where it's inserted into), it will never update that value, but you shouldn't need as well, because the created `TextEditingController`, should keep it on the screen.

This means, that if you want to update the value from a `TextFormField` that is already built, you should provide your own `TextEditingController` and set it's text accordingly.

```
TextEditingController _controller;

void initState(){
  _controller = TextEditingController(text: ic);
}

void build(BuildContext context) {

return TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter patient IC' : null,
  decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
    hintText: 'Patient IC e.g. 960XXXXXXXXX'
  ),
  onTap: () async {
    final String value = await Navigator.push(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisteredPatient())
    );
   setState(() => _controller.text = value);
  },
),
}
```

Comment: Just for further clarification, the initState only run once right? so once the setState runs the only thing that is changing is the controller itself?

Comment: When you call `setState` it will call the `build` method for the state that called it and `didUpdateWidget` for the children (if any) of that widget. The `initState` will _only_ be called, once per widget insert on the tree.